# python script being killed also stops the while loop from which it was called

Tags: bash, shell-script, python3, exit-status

I am uploading files using a python script, non-interactively and usually in a screen session. For big uploads, it sometimes happens that the script stops because it is killed (by python or the OS, I'm not sure):

```
...
uploading file000100 ...
uploading file000101 ...
Killed
```

The error code coming from the script is 137 -- I'm not sure how to get more 'diagnostic' information.

To keep uploading, I put the script in a while loop:

```
python3 upload_files.py; \
while [[ $? == 137 ]]; do \
      python3 upload_files.py; \
      sleep 1; \
done
```

This trick does not work though, because the while loop also ends when the script is killed. Does that make sense?

Comment: May I ask why python for the uploads? What protocol to you use? Is e.g. `rsync` an option? It has a resume option. Or are "big uploads" rather many files instead of large files?

Comment: Note that you don't need any of the `\ ` you have there. This isn't causing you any problems, it's just unnecessary.

Comment: @FelixJN I'm uploading to a site that has a python interface. I do have a file "succesful_uploads.txt"  to check what still needs to be done. So a working while loop would fit the bill!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to always restart the same script until it succeeds, you could do the following:

```
while ((1)) ; do
   python3 script.py && break
done
```

I.e. only break the infinite loop upon successfully finishing python. Otherwise the infinite loop will take over for restarting the script.

Comment: Thanks, will try! So in your example killing the python script  does not break the while loop -- I wonder why it does in mine?

Comment: @alle_meije I strongly assume that the error code for killing is different from the one for problems during execution. You are checking for 137, but you might have to check for another one, too. Try executing `python3 upload_files.py`, abort via CTRL+C, then check `echo $?`. Is it really `137` in that case?

Comment: Hi @FelixJN -- I'll mark your answer, because I found the problem thanks to your hints! In my while loop I first ran the python script -whcch returns an error code, quite consistently 137- and then `sleep` -which returns 0! Putting those the other way round works, as does your solution.